# Iterating with parseJSON & length

Tags: jquery, json

Morning all,

I'm trying to iterate a string and parse the data with `$.parseJSON`, and then send it to a select, but for some reason, when start the `for` nothing happens, no errors or anything like that.. simply, the script stops working (as an exit, in php)

The json:

```
{
"response": {
    "chars": {
        "0": {
            "guid": "728166",
            "name": "Pepito",
            "race": "1",
            "class": "6",
            "gender": "0",
            "level": "80",
            "money": "1412915382",
            "apoints": "0",
            "hpoints": "200000",
            "tkills": "1731",
            "title": "0"
        },
        "1": {
            "guid": "778879",
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "race": "7",
            "class": "8",
            "gender": "1",
            "level": "88",
            "money": "0",
            "apoints": "0",
            "hpoints": "0",
            "tkills": "0",
            "title": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The code:

```
var json = *this is the top json*;    
var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
for (var i=0; i<parsed.length; i++){
    console.log(parsed.response.chars[i].name);
}
```

which part is wrong? that to my knowledge, i see no fault.

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(parsed);` before the for loop to check that it's been parsed correctly. Plus you'll see the structure of `parsed` which should indicate why your loop doesn't work.

Comment: I already did, and yes, the parser works. If I remove the `for` and use `parsed.response.chars[0].name` shows the first entry, a test: http://jsfiddle.net/eLvqY/

Comment: Okay, well your looping the wrong node... check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over an object not an array!

```
var json = *this is the top json*;    
var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
for (var key in parsed.response.chars){
    console.log(key);
    console.log(parsed.response.chars[key].name);
}
```

Comment: jesus! really, is not an object is an array, do not know what I was thinking .. thank you! test: http://jsfiddle.net/PQEVn/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var json = *this is the top json*;    
var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
for (var i = 0; i < parsed.response.chars.length; i++){
    console.log(parsed.response.chars[i].name);
}
```